# Shortcut for adding one item to an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add just one item to an array in Javascript and use that array as an argument for a method. How can I complete this *with an easy syntax*.

I tried this:

```
[].push({ "value" : "test"});
```

But that only returns 1. I want the complete array as a return.
So any ides? Something similar to what I tried?

Comment: Ok, how would that be donein underscore.js? I'm open to use some kind of utility libary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
   [{ "value" : "test"}]
```

Comment: Of course! I was so into doing something with push so I was not thinking of it ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I didn't find anything in underscore, so my guilty conscience brought me to write it myself. You can simply extend the JavaScript Array object with your own `push` method that will return the new Array. A little like:

```
Array.prototype.betterPush = function(pushed){
this.push(pushed);
return this;
}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eVG9S/2/